# C# UdpClient.receive() not receiving responses to broadcast request

Tags: c#, udp, broadcast

I am trying to send data from my laptop to UDP server which communicates on port 30718. Data sending is correct, but when I want to receive response, program stucks on UdpClient.receive() method. i tried to sniff network with wireshark and it seem that response is delivered correctly, but c# will not receive it.
Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[4];
        data[0] = 0x00;
        data[1] = 0x01;
        data[2] = 0x00;
        data[3] = 0xF6;

        byte[] rcvPacket = new Byte[1024];
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255");
        client.EnableBroadcast = true;
        client.Connect(address, 30718);
        IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);


        client.Send(data, 4);
        rcvPacket = client.Receive(ref remoteIPEndPoint);

        string rcvData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvPacket);
        client.Close();  //close connection
    }
```

And here is output from wireshark (second picture is response to broadcast request):
[image: wireshark1]

[image: wireshark2]

Does anybody have solution for fixing this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: If You would check the searching engine first, it might be a duplicate of this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363729/c-sharp-application-not-receiving-packets-on-udpclient-receive

Comment: You don't need to call `Connect` and here is a quick sample in how to broadcast via UDP, https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/SharpSnmpLib/Messaging/Discoverer.cs

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution.
This is good example of sending broadcasts and receiving responses.
[C# How to do Network discovery using UDP Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/c-sharp-how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast)